# Contour Integral of $z \hspace{0.5mm} \exp(z^2)\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Compute the integral $$\int_C z \hspace{0.5mm} \exp(z^2)\,dz$$ $C$ from $1$ along the axes to $i$.

So far Im having trouble parametrising the curve $C$. Any hints?

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic and has an antiderivative which can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. The integral is just the difference of this antiderivative at the end points, no need to actually parametrise the curve

Comment: @MuhammadHarisRao How do you see immediately that the function is holomorphic? Also, out of curiosity, if you had to parametrise the curve, how would you do it?

Comment: The function is holomorphic because it is the composition and pointwise product of holomorphic functions

Comment: Paramerization: $$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}1-2t&t\leq \frac12\\i(2t-1)&t>\frac12\end{cases}$$ But as noted, you really don’t need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrization: $\gamma (t)=1-2t$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac 1  2$ and $\gamma(t)=i(2t-1)$ for $\frac 1  2 \leq t \leq 1$.

Also, $ze^{z^{2}}=\frac 1 2 \frac d {dz} e^{z^{2}}$. Hence, the value of the integral is $\frac 1 2 e^{(i^{2})}-\frac 1  2 e^{(1^2)}=\frac  1 2(e^{-1}-e)$